# Регулярное выражения, как найти строку у который больше чем одного символ подряд (-)?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Например:
str--sww :true

str---sww :true

str-sww---str:true

srt-sww-sww-srt:false

Вот что я нашел `/\-{2}/`

Но это только для двух подряд, а мне нужно для любого количества символа, кроме одного

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так `/\-{2,}/` или так `/\-\-+/`

Как настойчиво предлагают в комментариях, минус, вне квадратных скобок, можно не экранировать.

Comment: `/-{2,}/` или так `/--+/`

Comment: В общем случае минус это спецсимвол диапазона:  /[a-d]/

Comment: Это как раз *частный* случай, в *общем* случае, `-` не является специальным символом.

Comment: А тут уже зависит от вида и языка. Лучше экранировать, если нет дополнительной информации.

Comment: Не зависит, нет такого языка, где необходим `\-`. Нет, нельзя экранировать всё подряд. Сами попробуйте в консоли Chrome `/\-{2}/u.test("О-го!")`